# Fix badly encoded character

Tags: python, character-encoding

I visited a website that contained a character `ø` in the text. A character with unicode codepoint 248 (0xf8 in hexadecimal). Indeed, the Python console confirms that:

```py
>>> chr(248)
'ø'
```

But since I understand the text, I know that the character has been encoded with wrong encoding. It should be `ř` instead. And indeed, the [Windows-1250 codepoint table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) confirms that value 0xf8 equals to the character `ř`.

**What conversions should I apply to fix the text encoding? To transform `ø` to `ř`?**

I cannot figure out the correct sequence of functions. I, quite brainlessly, tried both:

```py
>>> chr(248).encode().decode('windows-1250')
'Ă¸'
```

and

```py
>>> chr(248).encode('windows-1250').decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/cp1250.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xf8' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

but, as you can see, none of it worked.

Comment: I think you are confusing different layers. Do you mean: how to interpret byte F8 as `ř`? Or a Unicode string (do not assume a binary representation) of `ø`? chr(248) is not `\0xf8`: it is the character with codepoint U+00F8 (no binary representation). For various conversion, put in binary string (encode), and then you decode (removing binary representation, using possibly a different encoding). But what it is confusing in your question: Unicode encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.) should not five a simple 0xf8 (or the contrary).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm sorry the encodings are so difficult to understand. Simply said, I see `ø` (ord 248) and I want to see `ř`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix badly decoded text, you have to find out what (bad) encoding was used to decode the text and what (good) encoding should have been used instead. Then, revert the bad changes and apply the good ones. In code:

```py
'bad string'.encode('bad encoding').decode('good encoding')
```

In this case, the bad encoding is `ISO-8859-1` (known also under an alias `Latin 1`) so the correct fix is:

```py
>>> chr(248).encode('latin_1').decode('windows-1250')
'ř'
```

Comment: `chr(248)` is unambiguously and by definition the Unicode code point "ø", aka [U+00F8](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f8/index.htm). Whatever it is that you are trying to explain seems to be based on an incorrect understanding of encodings and how Python implements them.

Comment: @tripleee I have a character `ø` and I know that it is a result of applying a bad encoding `ISO-8859-1` on the source, while the correct encoding `windows-1250` should be used. So I assumed that `'ø'.encode('latin_1').decode('windows-1250')` would fix it... And it appears it actually does. I use `chr(248)` and `ø` interchangeably just because of my fear of weird symbols in code. Do I have anything wrong? I very much appreciate your feedback.

Comment: No, you have a byte `b'\xf8'` (decimal 248) and you know which character it is supposed to represent. The fact that it represents ø in Unicode is a distraction here. Perhaps see also [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chararcter-encoding/info) which explains the concepts somewhat.

Comment: @tripleee The thing is, I don't have any bytes. If I had the byte `b'\xf8'`, I would easily apply the `windows-1250` encoding to get the correct result. But I have only the broken string.

Comment: You say it came from a web site, whose source is a sequence of bytes. If you interpreted those bytes as Latin-1, that's an interpretation which may or may not be correct. (Of  course, these days, you would hope that web sites would correctly tag all pages with the correct encoding metadata information, and probably also simply use UTF-8 everywhere.)

Comment: @tripleee I am sorry for that misleading story about a website. I would write that differently now that I've learnt more about it. A function from third-party library actually returns the broken string (regardless of actual origin) without giving me access to the bytes. Anyway, thank you for your effort, I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
chr(248).encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('windows-1250')
```

Comment: Thank you. I never used the [`raw_unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) codec.